# Can someone provide a simple example of using scope in a directive?

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I can't find any good example online of the scope property in a directive. I find it very confusing - what's the list of key's and values for? Where is the attribute's value used?

Can someone please provide a basic simple example?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Scope in Directives]

You can see the [JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/FHVD9/) or below.

Also, here is a [great article on the subject](http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/).

---

JS Fiddle Code (as shown in image)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <pass-object obj="obj2" itm="item.one"></pass-object>
</div>
```

JS 
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

```
myApp.directive('passObject', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { object: '=obj', itm: '=' },
        template: '<div>Hello, {{object.prop}}, {{itm}}!</div>'
    };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.obj2 = { prop: "world" };
    $scope.item = {"one": 1, "two": 2};
});
```